# Nyquist sampling

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling, computer-vision, nyquist, electrical-signal

I know that if $f_\mathrm{m}$ is the *"Nyquist frequency"* (max frequency) and $f_\mathrm{s}$  sampling rate then $f_\mathrm{s}>2f_\mathrm{m}$.

- Am I correct so far?

I have a signal $x(t)$ with max frequency $f_1$ and $h(t)$ with $f_2$ and we define $y(t)= h(t)*x(t)$ ($*$ for convolution) and we need to find the sampling frequency/Nyquist frequency of this function.

So the Nyquist frequency of $x(t)$ is $f_{\mathrm{s}_{x}} >2f_1$ and of $h(t)$ is $f_{\mathrm{s}_{h}} >2f_2$.

Now I saw that someone wrote that using the convolution theorem we get $Y(f)=H(f)X(f)$, so there must be that $f_\mathrm{s} \leq \min\{2f_1,2f_2 \}$ stating that this is an upper bound because frequency may cancel each other.

- Why is that true?

I must mention that he wrote $Nq(x)$ instead of $f_{\mathrm{s}_{x}}$ (I just understood that he meant the same),
also it's not supposed to be $f_\mathrm{s} \geq \min\{2f_1,2f_2 \}$ ?

I'm also not sure about is that $X(f)=0$ if $|f|>\frac{Nq(x)}{2}$.

- Why is that?

Comment: "someone wrote": Nope, not arguing with some unknown source about something that we both suspect is wrong. Cite, or find a better source.

Comment: @MarcusMüller if he is wrong can you answer me what is the correct answer? Thanks

Comment: well, you've derived the right answer already – convolution in time domain is equivalent to multiplication in frequency domain, and the support of two limited-support functions is the minimum common support. Thus, $f_s\ge \min\{f_{s1},f_{s2}\}$.

Comment: So the $\leq$ they wrote was a mistake? They said it’s less equal since frequency’s might cancel each other...

Comment: not repeating what I already wrote. You've got a math brain to use all for yourself!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89444/discussion-between-user152711-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: you also need to fix your symbols a little bit.  i would change "$x$" to "$t$".  then change "$f(x)$" to "$x(t)$" and "$g(x)$" to "$y(t)$".  then change "$F$" and "$G$" to "$X$" and "$Y$".  then use "$\omega$" **only** for *angular* frequency and use "$f$" for *ordinary* frequency for the arguments of $F(\cdot)$ and and $G(\cdot)$ and $H(\cdot)$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson what about the question itself? Can I send you in chat the answer I saw?

Comment: i don't want to think about the question until i am comfortable about the nomenclature.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I will fix it as soon as I am back home(this is the way it was written in origin). But can you please help me with it? Thank you very much

Comment: i didn't fix it yet, but **Nyquist frequency** (as ordinary, not *angular* frequency) is simply half of the sample rate, $f_\mathrm{s}/2$.  it is ***not*** the sample rate in any decent modern textbook or lit.  that abuse of notation needs to be corrected.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson
Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89447/discussion-between-user152711-and-robert-bristow-johnson).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson any comment about what I asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answered my I will answer using what I read on the internet,
"Nyquist frequency" is the max frequency we can get using given sampling rate.
the $f_s$ of convolution between 2 function is indeed the min of their max frequency, but I'm not sure yet about the part which stated that this is an upper bound because frequency may cancel each other. Since nobody here could answer it , but myself I'm marking this as an answer until  someone will be able to answer it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try.

> I know that if fm is the "Nyquist frequency" (max frequency) and fs
>   sampling rate then fs>2fm.
>
> Am I correct so far?

No.

The Nyquist frequency is simply defined as half the same rate. If your sample rate is 48kHz, your Nyquist frequency is 24kHz no matter what and how you sample anything.

You may have signals that have frequency content above the Nyquist frequency. If that's the case, you will get aliasing when you sample. However the Nyquist frequency is completely independent from the frequency content of the signal. The frequency content only determines whether you get aliasing or not.

Since you already started with a wrong assumption, the rest of your question as written doesn't make a lot of sense.

I think you are just confusing the terms "bandwitdh" and "Nyquist frequency" and what you are asking is *"I convolve a signal of bandwidth $f_1$ with a signal of bandwidth $f_2$: what's the bandwidth of the result?"*. If that's your question, please re-phrase as such. That answer would be $min(f_1,f_2)$

Comment: Thank you , but it’s not supposed to be the min?

Comment: Yes, of course. Corrected

Comment: also you didn’t referred to one of my question , the claim that it is less equal to it, since frequency may cancel each other..

Comment: Well, it's more complicated than that. For example, if you convolve two sine waves of different frequencies, the result will be zero. If your question is really about bandwidth, then please rephrase or ask a new one and  so it is clear what specifically you want to know.